# how to tag a network file use applescript

Tags: macos, applescript, file-permissions, finder, nas

I have googled a solution like that

```sh
#!/bin/bash
osascript -e "tell application \"Finder\" to set label index of alias POSIX file \"/Users/myname/Documents/example.txt\" to 2"
```

to flag the `example.txt` in my Documents directory to red color.

But when I change the file path to network file

e.g. a file in my nas server `/Volumes/mynas_home/1.txt`

and it reported

`can't convert file "mynas_home:1.txt" to “integer” type`

I have also tried

```
#!/bin/bash
xattr -wx com.apple.FinderInfo "0000000000000000000C00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" "/Volumes/mynas_home/1.txt"
```

and https://github.com/jdberry/tag
to flag color tag
They are both working but they are too slow to show the color tag for file in nas server.

So I still want to use applescript `tell application "Finder" to set label index of`,but it's not working in network file.

How to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Try HFS path: `...set label index of alias "mynas_home:1.txt" to 2` or `...set label index of file "mynas_home:1.txt" to 2`. For an external volume it's much easier to use than the *POSIX path-POSIX file-alias* dance

Comment: tried,the error is "Can\U2019t set alias \"mynas_home:1.txt\" to 2"  and "Can\U2019t set file \"mynas_home:1.txt\" to 2"

Comment: This is very strange because the error; [`-10006`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_codes.html) indicates _"The write operation was denied."_, and the file's permissions [`0777/-rwxrwxrwx`](http://www.filepermissions.com/file-permission/0777) do indicate that you have permission to; _Read_, _Write_, and _Execute_. Perhaps this is a _NAS Share_ related issue/bug.

Comment: It's a long shot, but maybe you could try [this](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/applescript-fails-on-nas-share.1991670/page-2#post-23355308).  Which is: **1)** Unmount `/Volumes/home`, **2)** Then in your Terminal application run `mkdir /Volumes/home` (or create the directory manually via the "Finder") **3)** Remounted the volume/share again.  (it should automounted as `home-1` i.e. force automounter numbering) **4)** Update the filepath specified in your `osascript` command to `/Volumes/home-1/1.txt` and re-run your `osascript` command again.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to set label index of (POSIX file "/path/to/filename.ext" as alias) to 2'
```

Note that by using a single-quote `'` vs. a double-quote `"` surrounding the *command* executed by `osascript`, it eliminates the *backslash escaping* of the double-quote `\"` within the *command*.

So, assuming the fully qualified POSIX pathname is: `/Volumes/mynas_home/1.txt`

Then use:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to set label index of (POSIX file "/Volumes/mynas_home/1.txt" as alias) to 2'
```

---

Also, as mentioned in a comment to the OP by vadian, use an HFS path instead.

Note that in the following example, using the fully qualified POSIX pathname provided in the OP and converted to an HFS path, it can be any of the following three variants:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to set label index of alias "mynas_home:1.txt" to 2'
```

Or:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to set label index of file "mynas_home:1.txt" to 2'
```

Or:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to set label index of item "mynas_home:1.txt" to 2'
```

As you can see in this instance `alias`, `file` and `item` are interchangeable.

Comment: tried,I have updated the question to show to result